# Filtering a collection of inherited objects

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, collections

I have a base class

```
public abstract AbstractThing { };
```

And lots of classes that inherit from it

```
public ThingA extends AbstractThing { };
public ThingB extends AbstractThing { };
...
public ThingY extends AbstractThing { };
```

I have a `ThingCollector` object that contains a set of Thing objects, i.e.:

```
public class ThingCollector {
  public void add(AbstractThing newThing);
}
```

The ThingCollector class also contains methods that allow:

1. Querying what kinds of concrete things it holds, e.g.

   `public Set<Class<? extends AbstractThing>> containsTypes();`
2. Obtaining the subset of things of a particular concrete type, e.g.

   `public <S extends AbstractMeasurement> Set<S> getSubset(Class<S> type);`

At the moment my `ThingCollector` implementation contains a private field of type `Set<AbstractThing>`.  The `add(...)` method adds everything to this same Set object.  The `containsTypes()` and `getSubset(...)` methods weave their magic using reflection while iterating over the Set.

*This works, but it seems messy.*  I'm convinced there must be a better way!

*Can you suggest other ways I can structure my solution?*  I did consider having `ThingCollector` maintain a separate Set for each individual type that extends `AbstractThing`, but:

1. That would mean `ThingCollector` would potentially contain dozens of Set objects.  And in most use-cases, nearly all of these sets would be empty.  Even though there's a family of a few dozen Things that inherit from `AbstractThing`, in practice only a few different types of Things will be contained in any given `ThingCollector`.
2. It's also messy; every time I define another Set within `ThingCollector`, I also need to add the new methods `add(ThingZ t)` and `getThingZSubset()`.

Is there a better way?  *Is there a design pattern or different class organisation that might help me here?*  I'm not beholden to the interface above for querying and subsetting the contents of the `ThingCollector` - all suggestions considered!

Comment: I should also add... although 3rd party libraries (like the suggested Guava) do exist, I would like to avoid using them in this case.

Comment: You should show your implementation code - "weave their magic using reflection" isn't enough for us to know what can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `Map<Class,Set>` as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ThingCollector {

    Map<Class,Set> map = new HashMap<Class,Set>();

    public void add( AbstractThing newThing )
    {
        Class clazz = newThing.getClass();

        Set set = map.get( clazz );
        if ( set == null )
        {
            set = new HashSet();
            map.put( clazz, set );
        }

        set.add( newThing );
    }

    public <S extends AbstractThing> Set<S> getSubset( Class<S> type )
    {
        return map.get( type );
    }
}
```

Bonus points for using a [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) Multimap to make your life even easier.

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty similar to the implementation I've got now, which gives me confidence that it's a good way to do it.

Unfortunately, there're too many hoops to jump through at work to get approval to use 3rd party libraries like Guava, even if they're open source.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering elements based on type, you could use Guava's [`Iterables.filter(Iterable, Class)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29), which is specifically meant for that purpose. Assuming `ThingCollector` contains a `Set<AbstractThing>` named `innerSet`:

```
public <S extends AbstractThing> Set<S> getSubset(Class<S> type) {
    return Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.filter(innerSet, type));
}
```

As for implementing `containsTypes()`, simply iterate over each element and call [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) on it, adding the result to a `Set<Class<? extends AbstractThing>>`, which is returned. Or use Guava's [`Iterables.transform(Iterable, Function)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) if you want to be fancy:

```
public Set<Class<? extends AbstractThing>> containsTypes() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.transform(
          innerSet,
          new Function<AbstractThing, Class<? extends AbstractThing>>() {
              @Override
              public Class<? extends AbstractThing> apply(AbstractThing thing) {
                  return thing.getClass();
              }
          }));
}
```

Disclaimer: examples are untested.